# How to Delete a number columns in all csv files inside of a directory

Tags: excel, csv, command-line, command

I have a massive amount of csv's inside of a directory, all of which I need to only keep the first 6 columns and delete the rest.

Is there a way (possibly within the command line) to automate this process? I looked online but my limited knowledge maybe hasn't allowed me to query google effectively.

Thank you,
Kind Regards

Comment: You could look into using `cut` for this, but if you CSV files use things like double quotes to include a comma in a field, you need a CSV parser such as [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/).

Comment: You could use VBA - loop through all the files in the directory, open the file, delete all content to the right of column E, save and close.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot - this will go through all csv files in the designated location and clear all content beyond the first 6 columns:

```
Sub ParseCSVFiles()

Dim strfile As String, dirtosearch As String
Dim csvfile As Workbook

'Modify this directory location as needed
mydir = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\TestDirectory\"

strfile = Dir(mydir & "*csv*")

Do While Len(strfile) > 0
    Set csvfile = Workbooks.Open(mydir & strfile)
    csvfile.Sheets(1).Range("G1:XFD1048576").ClearContents
    csvfile.Close True
    Set csvfile = Nothing
    strfile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Of course - beware when running code like this - make sure this is what you want to do, because after code like this runs you won't be able to undo the changes made. I'd suggest running this on a test directory like I did above first.

Comment: Hi, Im sorry if this is a noob question, but how do I run that code?